# Django: How to pre-enter data in a form?

Tags: python, django

I have got a quotation that I would like to convert in a project. If a quotation has been approved, it will be converted in a new project. I`ve got two models, one for the quotation and one for the project. To achieve this, I am thinking to add a button Create Project from Quotation. This button will create a new project based on the Project Model. Now, I am trying to find a way to pre-enter some data from the quotation in the new Project model entry.

What should I add to my `{% url 'projects:create_project' %}` to pre-enter the project name and link it to the quotation?

**Project View**

**models.py**

```
class Project(models.Model):
    
    PROJECT_TYPE = (      
        (0, 'Service'),
        (1, 'Others'),
        )
   
        
    user = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    quote = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    type = models.IntegerField(choices=PROJECT_TYPE,default=1) 
    description = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    po_number = models.CharField(max_length=30)    
    report = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    decimal = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    budget = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)  
    system = models.IntegerField(choices=SYSTEM,default=1)
    invoiced = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True)    
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def create_project(request):
    projects = Project.objects.all()
    form = ProjectForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        project = form.save(commit=False)
        project.save()
        return render(request, 'projects/index_jobs.html', {'project': project,'projects': projects})
    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, 'projects/create_project.html', context)
```

Many Thanks,

Comment: You can provide initial data to a form. Take a look at this; https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/initial-form-data-django-forms/

Comment: Can you share the view behind `create:project` together with the relevant models (and views)?

Comment: Thanks, I need to find a way to not have fixed data entered the form but the data from the quotation model entry. If a quote is accepted, I'll create a project from it and copy data from the quote model